# jQuery grouping plugin

Tags: jquery

Is there any jQuery plugin that can group data - either list or table - based on my criteria?

For example:

```
$("table").grouping({column: 1});
```

or

```
$("ul li").grouping({getgroup: function(item) { 
   return $(item).text().substr(0, 10); }
});
```

Something like this. The point here is that I need to change group dynamically - for example, user clicks "group by column 2" and I call $("table").groupby({column: 2}) and table is re-structured (and orders are grouped by customer company instead of customer name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, jqGrid can do this - finally, oh yeah! So I change the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[tableGroup](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/tablegroup/) (in combination with tablesorter?) seems to be doing what you want but also seems unmaintained

Comment: Yes, two years old is very old... but I think I can tweak it if there's nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/) plugin for jQuery. It can at least fix your table sorting problem.

Comment: I don't have any sorting problem.